# Horizontal Scroll lag on UIScrollview with UITableviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a paging enabled `UIScrollView` which contains several `UITableView`s. It's working all fine with scrolling vertically on `UITableView` and scrolling horizontally on `UIScrollView`. But to be able to scroll horizontally I need to wait until vertical scroll of `UITableView` is finished.

On Twitter's iPhone app's timeline tab, I think same architecture is used and I can scroll horizontally no matter if `UITableView` is scrolling or not.

Comment: Read up the docs on `UIGestureRecognizer`. Scroll views use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (declared as `panGestureRecognizer` on the scroll view) to detect scrolls. The `delaysContentTouches` property might interest you.

Comment: I created a subclass of UIScrollView and added this code to be able to detect more than one gesture recognizer. <code>- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer </code>  At the moment it's working fine like i wanted but not quite stable. Sometimes when i drag really fast, paging stacks between pages of UIScrollView